# How Can I create a grid layout of images in Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry

How can I make a grid of images in Blackberry. I would like to see a sample code that creates a grid layout with bitmaps and the bitmaps should be able expand to fit to screen when a user clicks or touches them.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You tend to get answer on SO, if you show what effort you have taken. It is not a 'do my homework' kind of site.

Comment: Thank you fellows. I will try to do something.

Answer (score 1):

This documentation on creating a [grid layout](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17971/Create_grid_layout_877557_11.jsp) from the blackberry website might help you with creating a grid of images.

For loading bitmap, there is documentation also available on the blackberry website called a [bitmap field](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Bitmap_field_1303007_11.jsp).

Further details on handling clicks and combining the grid and images might be found in this related stackoverflow question: [How to add images to the grid view and adding click function to these images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420248/how-to-add-images-to-the-grid-view-and-adding-click-function-to-these-images)

Making an image go fullscreen when clicked is an exercise left to the reader (for now).

Comment: Thanks Ryan...I am 2 weeks old to blackberry development so I am yet to try something. When I do I will post it here. Thank you again for the links. It is a good place to start.